# Routing Error No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, controller

I'm sorry to bother again, but these routes drive me crazy, on my app later that the user create the new car it must show the car created when the user push "new car".

```
<div class="container">
    <h2>new car registration</h2>

    <%= form_for ([@user,@car]) do |f| %>
      <div><%= f.label :brand %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :brand %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :color %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :color %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :model %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :model %></div>

      <div><%= f.label :year %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :year %></div>

      <div><%= f.submit "new car",:class => "btn btn-primary" %></div>
    <% end %>
    <br />
    <%= link_to "Back", current_user,:class => "btn btn-primary"  %>
  </div>
```

ok my Carscontroller is this:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.car.build
end

def create
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.car.build(params[:car])
      if @car.save
        #flash[:notice] = "new car created success"
        redirect_to user_car_path#current_user, :flash => { :notice => "car created!" }
      else
        redirect_to new_user_car_path ,:flash => { :notice => "sorry try again :(" }
      end
end

def show
  @car = current_user.car.find(params[:id])
  #@car = Car.find(params[:id])
  #redirect_to user_car_path
end

def index
    @car=Car.all
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html  #index.html.erb
    format.json  { render :json => @car }
  end
 end
end
```

so, when the user push new car it shows

```
Routing Error

No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"cars"}
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

instead of showing the new car

here is my routes.rb

```
Estaciones::Application.routes.draw do
root :to => "static_pages#home"
match '/contact', :to=>'static_pages#contact'
match '/about', :to=>'static_pages#about'
devise_for :users
resources :users do
resources :cars
```

end

Comment: Why did you comment `redirect_to user_car_path` in show action?

Comment: because if I uncomment that line i got this message from the explorer This webpage has a redirect loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources

Comment: ok i tried that and I got this error: 

    No route matches {:action=>"show", :user_id=>#<Car id: 21, user_id: 27, brand: "BMW", model: "zurf", year: 2010, color: "black", created_at: "2012-07-25 21:02:37", updated_at: "2012-07-25 21:02:37">, :controller=>"cars"}

Comment: I kept editing my answer, try the second option in my above answer.

Comment: Also make sure your associations are in place, so User has_many :cars AND Car belongs_to :user

Answer (score 1):

Your show action should be something like this:

```
 def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])     
    @car = @user.cars.find(params[:id]) 
    redirect_to user_car_path(@user, @car)  
 end
```

Let me know if this doesnt work.

**EDIT:** There is an error in your routes.rb, its missing additional keyword `end`. It will be solved if you do that

Comment: ok, I tried that and got this error

    Routing Error

    No route matches [POST] "/users/27/cars/22"

Comment: @Asantoya17, There is error in your routes.rb see my edit. Let me know if this works or not

Comment: @Asantoya17, what was you error? is it missing keyword `end`?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your config/routes.rb file?  I would almost think you don't have the nested routes setup in there correctly, but seeing the file would help.